# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to use Django-recurrence module. Without the javascript_catalog under "setting up internationalization" according to instruction :

```
# If you already have a js_info_dict dictionary, just add
# 'recurrence' to the existing 'packages' tuple.
js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('recurrence', ),
}

# jsi18n can be anything you like here
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
)
```

All I see even before internationalization, is below:
 - The upper part of the reccurrence "javascript-image" is not showing. The green text part(Add Rule and Add date) is the only thing showing:

```
+Add rule+Add date
```

What I am expecting according to documentation is shown below:

[image]

app/urls.py

```
js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('recurrence', ),
}

urlpatterns = patterns(#'',
    (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
    url(r'^room/$', CreateConfRoom_Sch.as_view(), name='CreateConfRoom_Sch'),
```

app/forms.py

```
class ScheduleConfRoom(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ('name', 'room', 'message', 'recurrences',)
        widgets = {
            'message': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 25, 'rows': 6}),
        }
```

app/views.py

```
class CreateConfRoom_Sch(CreateView):
    form_class = ScheduleConfRoom
    template_name = "schedule.html"
    success_url = '/'
```

app/models.py

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Example')
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room) # default='Empty')
    message = models.CharField(max_length=918)
    recurrences = RecurrenceField()
```

schedule.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'upload_file' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Please help!!! What did I do wrong? The error in the subject shows when I have the javascript_catalog in the urls.py. But When I don't have it, only "+Add Rule +Add date" shows.

```
AttributeError at /schedule/room/
'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.199:8000/schedule/room/

Django Version:     1.8.13
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve, line 367
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3.4
Python Version:     3.4.4
```

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

                                resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve

                                    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

     ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve

                                    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

     ...
▶ Local vars
```

First Trace

```
urlconf 'mal.urls'
middleware_method <bound method SecurityMiddleware.process_request of <django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware object at 0x8091b7a20>>
response    None
resolver    <RegexURLResolver 'mal.urls' (None:None) ^/>
self        <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x80836cc88>
```

Second trace

```
pattern <RegexURLResolver <module 'app.urls' from '/usr/home/msg/code/mal/app/urls.py'> (None:None) ^schedule/>
sub_tried   None
new_path    'schedule/room/'
match   <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='/'>
path    '/schedule/room/'
tried   [[<RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (admin:admin) ^admin/>],
        [<RegexURLResolver <module 'allauth.urls' from '/usr/home/msg/code/mal/allauth/urls.py'> (None:None) ^accounts/>],
        [<RegexURLResolver <module 'app.urls' from '/usr/home/msg/code/mal/app/urls.py'> (None:None) ^upload/>]]
self    <RegexURLResolver 'mal.urls' (None:None) ^/>
```

Third Trace

```
pattern  'app.views'
new_path 'room/'
match    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='schedule/'>
path    'schedule/room/'
sub_match   None
tried   [[<RegexURLPattern None ^jsi18n/$>]]
self    <RegexURLResolver <module 'app.urls' from '/usr/home/msg/code/mal/app/urls.py'> (None:None) ^schedule/>
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback! :)

Comment: What is the *full traceback* of the error? If you see the error message in the browser (only when `DEBUG` is set to true), look for the *switch to copy-and-paste view* for the traceback before copying the information to paste here.

Comment: That is only the error message, not the full traceback (which will show how Django got to that specific line).

Comment: I see... once sec...

Comment: Traceback added above.

Comment: Please show the full `app/urls.py` file.

Comment: @Divino: so the traceback shows the pattern that failed is `'app.views'`; this is missing from the contents of your `app/urls.py` file you posted here; is that file complete?

Comment: Yes, very complete.

Answer (score 0):

The `locals` information of your traceback shows it tried to use the following *string* as a match pattern:

```
pattern  'app.views'
```

That string was taken from the `urlpatterns` sequence in your `app/urls.py` file, which you only posted *part* of.

In addition, you forgot the `url` function on the first rule:

```
(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
# ^ no url
```

That makes it just a tuple, and the first element is then expected to be a regular expression. Add in the `url` call:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(#'',
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
    url(r'^room/$', CreateConfRoom_Sch.as_view(), name='CreateConfRoom_Sch'),
```

You'll need to fix *all* your rules however.

Comment: @Divino: did you actually restart your server?

Comment: @Divino: and where does `app.views` come from? That's the pattern that gives the exception.

Comment: Thanks Martin for pointing me to look at URL again.Yes URL was the issue. The URL was "urlpatterns = patterns(.....)" Now, I updated it to "urlpatterns = [..]"